# Show new comments replies on proposed change screen without requiring screen refresh

Tags: feature-request, documentation

1. I added a comment to a proposed change
2. Someone responded to it

Expected: I would see a little grey [new comments have been added] button below the comments section on the screen, like I would see on a question

Currently: don't see any on-screen notification within the proposed change without refreshing. It does show up though in my inbox in the header (clicking there just refreshes the page.